# Mesma url funciona as vezes sim e outras não

Tags: html, html5, formulário, rotas, carregamento

Eu estou com um formulário web, em que tenho este código:

```
<form action="../../MenuPrincipal" method="POST" class="form-inline">

<button type="submit">
</form>
```

e minha estrutura de arquivos está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu formulário esta no arquivo `pesquisasSp1Pesquisar.cshtml`

O problema é o seguinte... Quando eu faço o submit, ele vai para a url correta, mas com este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que a url está correta porque se eu clicar la e apertar enter, recarregando, ela abre corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS:** Não funciona se eu apertar F5.

Para mostrar melhor oque está acontecendo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DHWIXroacGBZI-g3NDxbqZdUjleNagcS/view?usp=sharing

---

**EDIT1:** A pedido do Alisson, troquei a minha action para pesquisaSp1Pesquisar, a fim de chamar o OnPost que esta nesta página. Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

Comment: Aparentemente o problema é você estar dando POST na rota Menu/MenuPrincipal e ela só tem previsto o GET.

Comment: @AlissonMarqui. Eu tenho o get da pagina feito e em relação ao meu post tenho apenas isso: `public IActionResult OnPost(){ return Page();}`. Está errado eu deixar a action do form daquele jeito?

Comment: Você realmente vai fazer um POST de alguma informação, ou quer apenas redirecionar de uma pagina para outra ? Este OnPost esta no MenuPrincipal ?

Comment: Eu vou fazer o post de algumas informações sim... O OnPost está no arquivo .cs da pagina pesquisasSp1Pesquisar

Comment: No seu form você esta apontando para um Post na rota de MenuPrincipal, então este OnPost deve ficar lá.

Comment: entao no meu onpost, devo fazer uma redirect para assim conseguir voltar para o MenuPrincipal?

Comment: se eu remover o "action" do form e colocar no meu onpost um `Response.Redirect("../../MenuPrincipal")` então em teoria era pra funcionar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95638/discussion-between-alisson-marqui-and-lima).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu form esta fazendo um POST no arquivo MenuPrincipal, este arquivo não possui um método OnPost por este motivo você recebe o erro 400. Ao utilizar o F5 o navegador tenta refazer a ultima ação, no caso ele esta tentando reenviar o POST por isso o erro persiste, ao mandar o navegador recarregar a pagina igual você fez no vídeo, o navegador solicita o GET na rota, por isso funciona.

Conforme as informações que você passou nos comentários, o método POST que você deseja acionar esta em pesquisasSp1Pesquisar.cs, como a view onde esta o form esta no mesmo arquivo .cs você pode tirar o action do form assim ele vai buscar nesse mesmo arquivo pelo OnPost.

No OnPost você vai tratar os dados e fazer um redirect para o GET do MenuPrincipal, algo como `Response.Redirect("../../MenuPrincipal")` como isso ele retornara a view corretamente.

---

**EDIT**

Conforme discussão no chat com o Lima, descobrimos que também faltava ajustar o @Model da view para apontar para o arquivo .cs correto.

Comment: Foi oque eu deduzi, pela sua explicação nos comentários... eu removi a action e coloquei o response.redirect no onpost, mas ele parece que apenas recarrega a página do form, não dá mais o erro 400, mas não vai para a rota, apenas recarrega a pagina do form. Tentei debugar o código dentro do onpost, mas parece que nem está passando por lá

Comment: @Lima na action do Form aponte para o OnPost da pesquisasSp1Pesquisar, por exemplo, `action='/pesquisa/pesquisasSp1Pesquisar'`

Comment: vou deixar um edit com o print de oque apareceu. Novamente não debugou